# What exactly does the expression "higher straight-in minimums" describe as "higher" relative to which value?

Tags: terminology, aeronautical-charts, jeppesen, symbology, minimums

What does the description of note 1 that I marked in the image mean? What exactly does the expression "higher straight-in minimums" describe as "higher" relative to which value? And how and when do I use RVR 1800m or RVR 2200m as the circle-to-land minimum if these are the intended values? Because there is "approach lights have no effect on circling minimums" information for the ALS system.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's visibility.

For Cat B, your required circling vis is 1600m, UNLESS the ALS is out of service (and the non-CDFA case) - in which case you need 2000m (which is the "higher straight-in minimums").

The ALS-out mins aren't higher than the Cat C or D circling mins, so those lines don't have the "1" note, just A and B.

It makes sense that if you need "this" vis when the ALS is out of service, you don't ignore that higher requirement just because you're circling.

Comment: What you said is very logical and thank you for the answer, but what I don't understand is that the word "or" is used in the note below. So I can't use the minimum visibility value of 1600m while ALS is out? To be more descriptive, wouldn't it be logical to write "If ALS out, use the straight-in approach minimum values" in the note section?

Comment: Also, I would appreciate it if you could comment on the last image I added because there are 2 RVR values higher than 1500m and 1600m visibility: RVR 1800m and RVR 2200m. In this case, does "or higher straight-in minimums" mean the value higher than the circle-to-land value, or does it mean the highest value from the straight-in landing RVR values? (Will the RVR 1800m or RVR 2200M be used? Will the RVR 1800m or RVR 2200M be used? And under what conditions will it be used? Because there is no condition other than ALS out which is RVR 2200m.)